# Correct permissions to access the file location of image

Tags: php, image

I have this code where I can upload images. Previously, I'm having trouble changing the path/directory of the folder. And its working fine now. I have the correct path inside my database and also the image is being saved into the correct folder.

My coding :

```
<table id="details" height="100">
<tr>
    <td>Select Image </td>
    <td> : </td>
    <td><input type="file" name="image" class="ed"></td>
</tr>
</table>


if (!isset($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']))
{
   echo "";
}
else
{
   $file=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
   $image= addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
   $image_name= addslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);

   $location= $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/ehars/photo/';
   move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $location .    $_FILES["image"]["name"]);
   $save=mysql_query("INSERT INTO photo (location,emp_id) VALUES ('$location','$emp_id')");                 
}
```

Path in my db :

[image]

Image saved in the folder :

[image]

However, when I try to view the picture inside the folder, I cannot view it. It says like in the photo below. Is there something wrong with my code? Or do I need to enable something so that I can view my photo? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: What does `chmod($path, 0777)` do for you? I know it's Windows and `chmod` is a part of GNU/Linux, but maybe it's going to emulate the desired behavior to some extent.

Comment: Additionally, you could open the file in some text editor and inspect if it begins with the desired [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_format#Magic_number) so that you know its contents are fine.

Comment: A couple of obvious problems with this code. 1. You are never checking the `$_FILES['images']['error']` array item and 2. If 2 users use the same filename for there picture you will over write images. 3. heaven only knows what all that `addslashes` stuff is all about

Comment: This error is not due to your code, but try to upload any other `extension` image and open with some other `photo viewer` application. Check if the same error occurs.Because I am doing the same way as you are and working fine with me.

Comment: Hi @learner, I've tried uploading different extension and even tried opening it with different photo viewer application. Unfortunately, the problem still occur. I still cannot view my photo. May I know what photo viewer application you're using?

Comment: Please just check your `php.ini` file does you have enabled the `file_uploads = on`. I use the `windows Photo viewer`.

Comment: @learner Yup its already on. Based on your experience what else could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try uploading a `.jpg` file instead of a `.png`. Or using another photo viewer program.

There is/was a problem with Photo Viewer not loading `.png` files

[See this for a possible solution](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-pictures/windows-photo-viewer-stopped-opening-png-files/a8db9335-2278-4058-807e-894143f9518b)

Comment: I've tried, both .jpg and .png files can't be viewed. Same goes when I tried viewing from a different viewer. It still can't be viewed.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the discussion in the comments. I am sharing the code what I use to upload an image`(save to a dir)`.I also didn't understood why you are using `addslashes()`. Sorry about this!

Basically what I do is -

- created `dir` in my project folder
- Created an unique name for the file to store so that conflict does not happen

This is my html form where I get the file from the User.

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="save_blog.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="form-group">  
   <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="pwd">Image</label>      
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <input type="file" class="filestyle" name="image_upload" data-input="false" id="file_name"><label id="name_of_image_file"></label>
      </div>
</div>
</form>
```

And my `save_blog.php` looks like this.

```
$temp = explode(".",$_FILES["image_upload"]["name"]);
$unique_name_of_image = date('y-m-d') . "_".$user_id ."_".rand(1,9999)."." .end($temp);
$file_location = "$target_dir".$unique_name_of_image;

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image_upload"]["tmp_name"], $file_location)) {
//this prints the location of the file stored
#echo "$target_dir".$unique_name_of_image; echo "<br>";

    #$insert_blogs_with_image --> this is my insert string 

    save_to_database($insert_blogs_with_image);         
} else {
                #echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
}
```

Hope this will help to solve the problem. If this didn't help then use the sample tutorial shown by the [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp)